# Search contacts by phone is giving "No source available" exception

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-7, contacts

I downloaded this sample "Contact filtering and matching for Windows Phone"  from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286414%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

When I run it and select "phone" option and click search without filling a phone number it throws an exception that opens in a new tab:

```
"No Source Available. No source found. You need to load symbols in order to find the source for the current stack frame".
```

Can anybody help? because I'm trying to build something similar to that in my project but I keep getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have added contact in emulator :

- Name Toto
- Phone 0600000000

I run the application, select phone with 0600000000 in textbox.
I click on search button and it works good in my emulator.

In the sample project, if you select phone, you have to enter an integer value.

Comment: when I enter a phone number it works well. the problem is when I leave it empty

Comment: Add a condition : if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contactFilterString.Text))

Comment: I cant do that cz the search won't work then + this code is from msdn in case you noticed so I guess it should work but it's a matter of some configuration or something

Comment: @NadaNaoushi: You're trying to perform a search without any search value.  Don't do that.  Simple.  Done.  Congrats, you've won.

Comment: @Will, that's not a correct behavior! exceptions should be caught and not left like that. and why when I choose name option and leave it empty it retrieves all contacts without a problem ?

Comment: @NadaNaoushi: Then, when the user attempts to search with no text, instead of performing the search, get the full listing and return it to him.  `If(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText)){ /* return all */ } else { /* search */ }`.  The Aristocrats.